# Android - getIdentifier always returns 0 (library +application)

Tags: android, resources

I have Android project (com.appocaliptic.quizknife.app) which uses Android library (com.appocaliptic.quizknife.core).

What I am trying to do, is to get resource id of the picture which is the library. Path to the image is: *res/drawable-xhdpi/fr_200_133.png*

However, all tries with getIdentifier result 0. Where is the problem?

```
resId = getResources().getIdentifier("fr_200_133", "drawable", "com.appocaliptic.quizknife.core");
resId = getResources().getIdentifier("com.appocaliptic.quizknife.core:drawable/"+"fr_200_133", null, null);
resId = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/fr_200_133", null, "com.appocaliptic.quizknife.core");
```

Edited:

Ach, and in R.java there is drawable and corensponding attribute.

Comment: Does the system you are testing this on have a screen with xhdpi resolution?

Comment: @Squonk - That shouldn't matter when it comes to retrieving the id itself; only in retrieving the drawable associated with the id. Besides, for drawable resources, the system will find the [best match](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch), so it will use the xhdpi resource (after scaling) even on an ldpi device.

Comment: @TedHopp : Yes agreed - I forgot about the best match for drawable resources.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should not be using the library package name. Try this instead:

```
resId = getResources().getIdentifier("fr_200_133", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

(or `getContext().getPackageName()` if this is executing in a view).

The key is that you need to use the app's package name (as listed in the manifest) rather than the library's package name (which actually disappears when creating the app).

Comment: wow, it works O_o. Thanks a lot - btw - any source of this information ? All resources which I found they were suggesting use String package name. Thx.

Comment: @bluszcz - I think I picked up that idiom from an example somewhere. The key is that you need to use the app's package name (as listed in the manifest) rather than the library's package name (which actually disappears when creating the app).

Comment: I believe you should post your comment along with the reply - this is very crucial information ;)

Comment: The reason why this is best solution is because you are not using a hardcoded value!

Answer (score 40):

I faced the same problem: **"getIdentifier result 0"** and i solved it by removing image extension (*.jpg, *.jpeg,... etc) to be match the name as it in **R.java** file

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the same error and the only thing that worked was going about it in a different way:

```
resourceId = R.drawable.class.getField("fr_200_133").getInt(null);
```

Comment: This is reflection and not recommended.

Comment: @MalwinderSingh Can you explain why?

Comment: Unfortunately this is only thing that works for me as well. 
However reflection in production is not recommended unless absolutely necessary because reflection is prone to create problems later on e.g. when name of reflected "item" change.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue. I could resolve it similar to what Hussam Otri mentions. For example:

```
//This doesn't work
context.getResources().getIdentifier("audio_1.mp3", "raw", this.getPackageName()); 

//This works (strip off the file extension)
context.getResources().getIdentifier("audio_1", "raw", this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Also for me, that extension was the cause! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The name of image is underscore (underline) or "_" and I result okay
because compiler rename name of photo as sample: source:"img0001" after compile "imag_0001".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Language was Turkish and it replaced letter 'i' with 'ı' for all resource files. I replaced 'ı' with 'i' in the string resource name. Now my app is working well.
Code :

```
public static int getResId(String imageName ,Activity activity) {
        int resourceId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", activity.getPackageName());
        if (resourceId == 0) {
            imageName = imageName.replace("ı", "i");
            resourceId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", activity.getPackageName());
        }
        return resourceId;
    }
```