# How do I get the resource id of an image in jar-library if I know its name?

Tags: java, android, jar, resources

I try get identifier of image inside my `jar`-library from my app.

My `jar`-library have structure:

- com/mypackage/*.class
- res/drawable/icon_name.png

Then I include jar-library inside /libs of my app.

I try use:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("icon_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

But I get only 0.
I see more info on stackoverflow like [Android - getIdentifier always returns 0 (library +application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394688/android-getidentifier-always-returns-0-library-application) but not success.

I check availabled file by:

```
InputStream is = getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/drawable/icon_name.png");
```

and got a correct data, file is availble from app.

But `getIdentifier()` not work. What I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using XML to do your layout, add a TAG to it.  You can effectively use that as the unique identifier for it.

Comment: No, I don't use XML. I try get id of drawable from library. Then used id in 'NotificationCompat.Builder.addAction(id,...);' to create notofication's action.